# Parameter value set to 0 when send parameter to Web API

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a function to call API like this

```
async addOffDayReplacement(employeeId: string, days: number) {
    console.log(days);
    await Axios.post('/api/v1/leaveQuota/' + employeeId, {
        params: {
            additionalDays: days
        }
    });
}
```

And have API

```
[HttpPost("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> Update(string id, int additionalDays)
{
    await leaveService.AddReplacement(id, additionalDays);
    return true;
}
```

But the `additionalDays` in my API always 0 even when value that I sent from my service is not 0

Anybody know why? And how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an object as your second parameter which contains AdditionalDays property. Annotate that parameter with [FromBody].

```
[HttpPost("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> Update(string id, [FromBody] Model model)
{
    await leaveService.AddReplacement(id, model.AdditionalDays);
    return true;
}
```

Do not forget to define a Model class with AdditionalDays public property.

For details, take a look at this article: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Sep/11/Passing-multiple-simple-POST-Values-to-ASPNET-Web-API

Comment: I think you forgot the `[FromBody]` annotation

Comment: Thanks for the catch @ChrisSatchell. Just updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks.. I just realized since I receive 'application/json', i just cant receive single int parameter. And my variable name in model and interface javascript should be same

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the binding source, i.e. how your function can access it/how the parameter is passed (body, query, etc.), so using

`[FromBody]int additionalDays`

should fix it for you.

The reason why `string id` works is because you specified it in `[HttpPost("{id}")]`.

I'd recommend checking out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1 for more details and examples.

Comment: Since it's a POST request do you mean `[FromBody]`?

Comment: @phuzi Good catch, fixed it

Comment: I tried it before i post here. If i use [frombody], i getting error 400